# componentDidMount calling onPress?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

Have been working on a react project and in one of my screens when it mounts, the onPress of my buttons are being activated at the start and are then unable to be used. Found this out after the whole thing crashed when onPress activated a function (couldn't press anything on screen including the tabs, no content on screen either, so then changing it to just console log something I could see the buttons were just being called at the start. Not getting any error messages.

> componentDidMount

```
componentDidMount = async () => {
    var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
    var foo= []
    var foobyDoo= []
    var i = 0;

   // get firebase stuff

    var arrayWithKeys = []
    i = 0;
    while (i < monthYearArray.length) {
        arrayWithKeys.push([i, monthYearArray[i]])
        i++
    }



    this.setState({
        monthsAndYears: arrayWithKeys,
        firebaseArray: arrayToSet,
    })
}
```

> Render

```
render() {
    return (
        <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{
            flex: -1,
            justifyContent: 'space-between'
        }}>
            {this.state.monthsAndYears.map((item) => (
                <Button
                    key={item[0]}
                    title={this.state.monthIntMap[item[1].slice(0, 2)] + " " + item[1].slice(3,)}
                    onPress={this.someFunction} //This crashes the whole thing, if its changed to console.log
                                               // then it will log upon mounting and afterwords the buttons are useless
                />
            ))
            }
        </ScrollView>
    );
};
```

}

Thanks

Comment: `onPress={console.log("heh")}` here you are not assigning `onPress` a function, but the return value of that function (undefined). This will console log every render currently, not just on mount. What you are intending to pass it is a function like this `onPress={() => console.log("heh")}`

Comment: magic thanks, I realised I left the Touchable part in but that was just messing about with it. This fixed it though thanks